# Best time to catch an error C#

Tags: c#, exception

I'm trying to use the best possible practices for exception handling and I'm a little bit lost.

For example, if I have 4 methods (1 call the other one who call the other one...).
For each method, a custom exception of the same type can be thrown.

Let's say that I have an error that is thrown in 4th method. Do I need to catch it in the 3rd one or I can catch it in the first one?

Because if I respect the principle that an error needs to be caught as soon as possible, I should put catch in all of the 3 first method instead of only the first one.

```
Method1()
{
    Method2();
}

Method2()
{
    Method3();
}

Method3()
{
    Method4(); 
}

Method4()
{
    //Some code that could throw a customException
}
```

Comment: Exceptions should not be "*caught as soon as possible*", exceptions ***should be caught when they can be handled appropiately***

Comment: I'd like to know where the "as soon as possible" principle came from.

Comment: I read that on the Internet

Comment: Please provide a link to it

Comment: what principal? and what do you mean by "as soon as possible"?  Errors should be "caught" in the place where it is most appropriate to handle them. There is no requirement or principal to catch them "sooner".

Comment: I just want to avoid to catch same type of error in all my methods so I could just put a catch in my big method?

Comment: Yeah, this is a common misconception for programmers coming from other languages (particularly Python, which uses exceptions for control-flow, and Java which commands you to handle exceptions or explicitly declare them in your method signature) but in c# you should *not* use exceptions for control flow -- they should (generally) be handled by some sort of catch-all logger that will inform you that you have a bug in your program.

Comment: Ok, but if you did have a catch in all the methods, what do you plan on doing in the catch?

Comment: You have to decide, which method in the chain are you going to take appropriate action about the exception? That is the only place you really need to catch it.

Comment: @KirkWoll -- That depends on the type of exception.  If it's anticipated (e.g. you try to write to a file and it's locked) then you just catch it and deal with it in the catch block.  That's not a "bug".

Comment: In the catch I want to close my application, so log the error and close my app.

Comment: You need to catch every error before it propagates back up the stack to the root of the application where it will be automatically become an "Unhandled" exception and cause the app to crash.

Comment: @rory.ap, there are certain scenarios where that is true (SQL deadlocks or timeouts are one salient example) but generally speaking you shouldn't use exceptions.  i.e. `int.TryParse` vs `int.Parse` + exception handling.

Comment: @KirkWoll -- Eh, I don't buy that.  You just have to be smart about it.  The example I gave with the file access is a perfect example.  When you open a file to write to it, it doesn't make any sense to check *first* if it's locked, because it could become locked after you check it and before you open it.  Exception handling is the way to go there.  Just try to open it, and catch the exception.

Comment: So in fact, if I need to do something where I am, I can catch my error, but if I need to log and close my app, I can put a catch in my main method? It depends only of what I want to do?

Comment: @rory.ap, I agree with that example as well.  I think we are violently agreeing. ;)

Comment: @ÉmilePettersen-Coulombe -- That's exactly right.

Comment: Two golden rules:
1 – Only handle exceptions that you can actually do something about, and
2 – You can’t do anything about the vast majority of exceptions. Read: http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2008/05/30/foundations-of-programming-pt-8-back-to-basics-exceptions/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm trying to use the best possible practices for exception handling and I'm a little bit lost.

Writing robust software is hard.

> if I respect the principle that an error needs to be caught as soon as possible

That's a poor principle. What does *possibility* have to do with it?  The principle that you should only write *possible* code is not helpful. What does *time* have to do with it?  It's a tautology that the correct place to handle an exception is *where the exception can be correctly handled*; neither *sooner* nor *later* than that.

Where can an exception be correctly handled? That depends entirely on (1) the exception and (2) how you intend to handle it. That sounds like very unhelpful advice, but your question is incredibly vague! Let's leave exceptions out of it and just consider *computations*.  Where is the *best* place to put a computation?  Is it better to do computations earlier or later?  How could you possibly answer that question for all possible computations?

> I just want to avoid to catch same type of error in all my methods so I could just put a catch in my big method?

Well let's think about this. Suppose for the sake of argument that it is *correct* for each method to handle the exception.  Under what circumstances is it correct to move the exception handling out of each callee and into the caller?  That's easy to enumerate:

- The handlers must not depend on any state known only to the callees but not to the caller.
- The handlers have to do the same thing in each callee.
- The callees must not be called from anywhere other than the caller.

Is that the situation you're in? Then it is possible to move the handler into the caller without changing semantics, and thereby reducing duplicated code.

> I want to close my application, so log the error and close my app

Then put the handler as close to Main as possible.

Alternatively, handle the "I'm unloading the appdomain because I got an unhandled exception" event and put your handling logic there.

I note that if your app is shutting down abnormally like this *you have no guarantee that your logging system isn't the thing that blew up*, and you might be about to blow it up again. Be careful!

Comment: The mentioned "I'm unloading the appdomain because I got an unhandled exception" event should be the [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ea9wwze(v=vs.110).aspx), if I understand correctly.